# Print the number 5 as a reverse pattern in C

Tags: c

**C**
As you see in this code I'm trying to print the below pattern, Is the code is right to print the pattern cuz in my computer it show's wrong.

```
//To print this type of pattern
    //5 5 5 5 5 5 
    //5 5 5 5 5
    //5 5 5 5
    //5 5 5
    //5
int i, j, a=5;
for(i=0; i<=5; i++)
{
    for(j=i; j<=5; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", a);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d ", a);`  add space after %d.

Comment: Yeah, your code is almost working fine.  Were you really just wondering how to print a space after the 5?

Comment: Are blanks at the end (or beginning) of each line acceptable?

Comment: The last row has only one 5, 2nd last row has three 5's. To do this you can use `if` statements. Try to think about, you might be able to do it yourself

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your pattern looks strange. Is it intented to have the line with 2* `'5'` missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int height = 5;
    char line[height*2];
    
    for(int i=0; i<height*2; i+=2)
    {
        line[i]='0'+height;
        line[i+1]=' ';
    }

    for (int i=0; i<height; ++i)
    {
        printf("%.*s\n",2*(height-i), line);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Result

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5532KB
5 5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 
5 5 
5
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple mistakes here.
First, remember that counting in your loop starts at 0, so from 0 to 5 is actually 6 rounds through your top for loop. What you want is for i to range between [0-4] inclusive. To do this modify the `<=` loop condition to be `<`.

Additionally add a space after `"%d "` if you want spaces between the each 5.

Try running through it with pen and paper, there is another mistake in the j loop as well.

Comment: As you can see in the desired pattern, the first row has 6 * `'5'`.